# Transferring data from external Jazz drive into computer with windows 98

Tags: windows-98

I have an external Jazz hard drive that has been used to backup my files from computer with windows 98.  My computer crashed.  I have a second computer with windows 98 and the hard drive was taken from that computer and put into the first one.  I have Retrospect 5.6 but have lost the instructions on how to restore the files from the Jazz drive back into the computer.

I am unable to upgrade windows because of the accounting software that I am using.  It is dos based and windows 98 is the only thing that will support the software.

Does anyone know how I can get information to solve this problem?

Comment: You could look at DosBox (http://www.dosbox.com/) or other DOS emulators. Can you see the Jazz drive on the new computer?

Answer (score 3):

Iomega, on their [Jaz Drive Recovery page](http://iomega.com/data-recovery/jaz-recovery.html), suggests you use their Data Recovery service to get the files.  I'm not advocating that, just putting that out there.  They don't really want you to continue to use the old products.

Now that I got that out of the way, on their [Jaz Drive driver](https://iomega-na-en.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/16744) page, they indicate you don't need drivers to use it... you need their Iomegaware software.

> Drivers are small files containing the system files that allow your computer to recognize your Iomega drive. IomegaWare contains these drivers, along with special tools and important utilities that will help you format, protect, manage, and change settings for your Iomega Jaz drive. If you download IomegaWare, you do not need to download drivers.
>
> The latest version of IomegaWare supports all Jaz drives. Features like read/write protection, copy disk, etc. can be found by right-clicking on your Iomega Jaz drive icon (option-click on the icon for a Mac).
>
> Most operating systems will automatically detect your Iomega Jaz drive with native drivers. If your operating system is not detecting your drive, download the newest version of IomegaWare.

Now.... after ALL that nonsense from them, there is [THIS page for the USB and Parallel port Windows 98 drivers](https://iomega-na-en.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/16732).

However, if you would like to take their advice, Iomegaware 4.0.2 will work with Windows 98 according to [this download page](https://iomega-na-en.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/16442).

So, you have a choice there.  Download just the drivers so you can see the drive in Windows 98, and then have no Iomega tools to manipulate the drive or data.... or download the Iomegaware software like they recommend.

All this information is courtesy of the Iomega web site.